NServicebus SQL server performance issues
We have a problem where our NServicebus application can't handle all the messages in the SQL Server transport input queue.
The default SQL-query to select messages is:
WITH message AS (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM QueueName WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK) ORDER BY [RowVersion] ASC)
DELETE FROM message
OUTPUT deleted.Id, deleted.CorrelationId, deleted.ReplyToAddress,
deleted.Recoverable, CASE WHEN deleted.Expires IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(ms, GETUTCDATE(), deleted.Expires) END, deleted.Headers, deleted.Body;

We would like to configure this so that instead of only selecting 1 message we want to select a batch of 100. Is that possible, or do you know another way to improve the performance?

It looks kinda hardcoded https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.SqlServer/blob/300466acc4cb92abd2dbbe64b68e6dfa39498c36/src/NServiceBus.Transport.SqlServer/Queuing/SqlServerConstants.cs#L86 do you have index on rowVersion?

What performance issues are you running into? What is the required throughput and what is your current maximum? Maybe your performance issue is caused by something else?

Batching isn't designed into the NServiceBus SQL transport. This is because its optimized for transactional consistency between the "queue" and any "data" that gets modified in a single transaction. Meaning, each processed message is one database transaction.
More guidance on transport selection is available at: https://docs.particular.net/transports/selecting
If throughput is more important and you're using different techniques to ensure data consistency like outbox you could select a transport with a lower transaction model to achieve much higher throughputs.
For example, this is listed under the SQL Transport:
Advantages

SQL Server is already present in many organizations. This could result in lower licensing and training costs, as well as a reduction in operational risk, since the skills and knowledge required to run SQL Server are already present.
Mature tooling, such as SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and Azure Data Studio
Free to start with the SQL Server Express or Developer editions
Easy scale-out through competing consumers. Multiple instances of the same endpoint consume messages from a single queue.
Supports distributed transactions, allowing atomic message processing and data manipulation in database systems which also support distributed transactions (e.g. SQL Server), using the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)
Can store both queues and business data in a single backup, making it easier to restore a system to a consistent state

Disadvantages

Adds pressure to the database server due to polling for new messages
Depending on throughput, can add significant load to an existing SQL Server installation
Can have significant costs in Production for high throughput systems where extra servers or cores are required to support the load
= Inherently not designed as a messaging broker which can lead to lower performance and connection limitations when utilized for a larger system with many endpoints

When to select this transport

When it's not possible to introduce a native queueing technology
When the benefits of introducing a native queueing technology are outweighed by the cost of licensing, training, and ongoing maintenance compared with using existing -SQL Server infrastructure
For integration with a legacy application that uses SQL Server, using database triggers
When the system has a small number of endpoints or a medium number of endpoints with low throughput.

